# UPDATE statement conflicted with FOREIGN KEY constraint - How to fix?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]I have encountered an issue when I'm debugging my code that is to do with a SQL Server stored procedure I have

> "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_PATIENTS_DropdownCounty\". The conflict occurred in database \"****\", table \"dbo.DropdownCounty\", column 'County'

I am using the DropdownCounty table to populate a dropdown menu but when I try to update the web-page it is giving me the issue above. I have tried the CASCADE option in SQL itself.

The SQL Server stored procedure I am using is below

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[PatientDetailsUpdate]
    @PatientNumber INT,           
    @HospitalNumber NVARCHAR(50),  
    @HC_Number NCHAR(20),    
    @ID_Number_LegacyID NCHAR(20),    
    @ConsentToDatabase BIT,      
    @ConsentGivenDate DATETIME,   
    @Sex CHAR(6),     
    @Forename NVARCHAR(50),
    @Surname NVARCHAR(50),
    @MaidenName NCHAR(10),     
    @DateOfBirth DATETIME,      
    @Age NCHAR(10),    
    @AddressLine1 NVARCHAR(50), 
    @AddressLine2 NVARCHAR(50), 
    @AddressLine3_TownCity NVARCHAR(50), 
    @AddressLine4_Region NVARCHAR(50),  
    @County NCHAR(17),     
    @Country NCHAR(10),   
    @PostCode NVARCHAR(50), 
    @HomeTelNumber NVARCHAR(50),  
    @MobileTelNumber NVARCHAR(50),  
    @WorkTelNumber NVARCHAR(50),  
    @Email NVARCHAR(50),  
    @Notes NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE PATIENTS
   SET HospitalNumber = ISNULL (@HospitalNumber, HospitalNumber), 
       HC_Number = ISNULL (@HC_Number, HC_Number), 
       ID_Number_LegacyID = ISNULL (@ID_Number_LegacyID, ID_Number_LegacyID),   
       ConsentToDatabase = ISNULL (@ConsentToDatabase, ConsentToDatabase),     
       ConsentGivenDate = ISNULL (@ConsentGivenDate, ConsentGivenDate), 
       Sex = ISNULL (@Sex, Sex), 
       Forename = ISNULL (@Forename, Forename), 
       Surname = ISNULL(@Surname, Surname), 
       MaidenName = ISNULL (@MaidenName, MaidenName),   
       DateOfBirth = ISNULL (@DateOfBirth, DateOfBirth), 
       Age = ISNULL  (@Age,Age),
       AddressLine1= ISNULL(@AddressLine1, AddressLine1),
       AddressLine2= ISNULL(@AddressLine2, AddressLine2),
       AddressLine3_TownCity = ISNULL(@AddressLine3_TownCity, AddressLine3_TownCity),
       AddressLine4_Region  = ISNULL(@AddressLine4_Region, AddressLine4_Region),
       County = ISNULL(@County, County),
       Country = ISNULL(@Country, Country),
       PostCode = ISNULL(@PostCode, PostCode),
       HomeTelNumber = ISNULL(@HomeTelNumber, HomeTelNumber),
       MobileTelNumber = ISNULL(@MobileTelNumber, MobileTelNumber),
       WorkTelNumber = ISNULL(@WorkTelNumber, WorkTelNumber),
       Email = ISNULL(@Email, Email),
       Notes = ISNULL(@Notes, Notes)
   WHERE 
       PatientNumber = @PatientNumber
END
```

Do I need to use a LEFT JOIN to link the the tables?

Thanks in advance,

And I'm sorry but I'm only new to database stuff
I have included the values of what DropdownCounty looks like in its table

[image]

The second image I have uploaded is to help you understand what I'm trying to call whenever BtnUpdate is called

Comment: It fails because the value of `@Country` does not exist in your FK table `DropdownCounty`. So, what is the value of `@Country` and what are the current values in the `DropdownCounty` table? It might be that `@Country` is empty (ie. empty string and NOT null) and that you are not checking for this in your statement.

Comment: It would be really helpful to know the exact values used when the UPDATE Statement fails.  Are you able to capture that?  Perhaps by running SQL Server Profiler when you run it?

Comment: Please check to see what you're passing for the `County` in your stored procedure. Whatever you're passing sounds like it needs to also exist in your `DropdownCounty`.`County` SQL table and column and it doesn't.

Comment: County is present in both the PATIENTS table and DropdownCounty table. Both values are NCHAR as the County column is a foreign key in the PATIENTS table.

Comment: @KSib could it be that because I'm trying to update a field that is populated from another table through the Foreign Key?

Comment: @KarlB - obviously that is not true otherwise you would not receive this error. The value you are passing in `@Country` does not exist in `DropdownCounty` table at the time the update statement is executed. You can argue this all day but the short of it is that is a fact given the error. The only way to know what value is causing the issue is to debug or use sql profiler to get the actual value of `@country` and compare that with the values in the table `DropdownCounty`.

Comment: @Igor 'Country' is not the issue - it is 'County'

Comment: The problem is your update statement is passing a value in `County` that doesn't exist in your `DropdownCounty` table. Look at the first comment from @Igor and you'll figure it out. He just mis-typed `Country` when he meant `County`

Comment: @Igor I have added an image of what the DropdownCounty table looks like

Comment: @KarlB  - KSib is spot on. Also that is a type-o of mine (that I happen to repeat from copy/pasting), I meant to write `county` not `country`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a table `PATIENTS` that is linked with table `DropdownCounty` using a FK `CountyId` of type `int`. In your `UPDATE` statement on table `PATIENTS` you are trying to set the FK column `CountyId` using the `nchar` value of the County instead of using the pk value `CountyId`, that is why you are getting an error. You need to update it with the value of the primary key, that is what needs to be persisted back to the `PATIENTS` table.

Change your stored procedure to take in `@CountyId` of type `int` (*instead of `nchar`*)and use that instead in your `UPDATE` statement.

Your code displays the drop down, almost all drop down controls (*web, windows, wpf, whatever*) have the ability to have a display value and the underlying value (like a numeric identifier). This is the identifier your code needs to pass when calling the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
County = ISNULL(@County, County),
```

You're attempting to stuff the county name into the (poorly named) `County` column, when in fact it should contain the `CountyID`.

You can get around the problem by looking up the CountyID in your SQL, like this:

```
County = CASE @County WHEN NULL THEN County ELSE (SELECT CountyID FROM DropdownCounty WHERE County = @County) END
```

Comment: Hi John, the DropdownCounty table is used to populate a dropdown menu hence why I need to use the names of the counties in the web-application. When I try to update the details using the update query this is when I run into problems

Comment: Yep.  My solution accommodates that.  Pass the county name to the stored procedure and the SQL will do the rest.

Comment: Can I still keep the NChar or does it need changed?